# Limit up to 10 ids from table 1 and get all the records from table 2 which matches the ids of table 1

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have a table1 for example:

```
orderID userId orderName orderTime...
1         11
2.        12
3.        11
4.        14
5.        11
6.        13
7.        11
8.        15
9.        16
10.       11
...      ...
```

I have another table table2:

```
table2ID orderID item    price ....
101       1       Apple   1.99
102       1       Banana  2.99
103       1       Grapes  0.99
104       4       pizza   6.99
105       4       drink   0.99
105.      3       chicken 1.99
106.      3       apple   1.99
```

I have tried this :

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM `table1` a
    RIGHT JOIN table2 b on a.orderID = b.orderID 
    WHERE a.userID = 11 order by a.`orderTime` DESC LIMIT 25;
```

I want to get upto 10 unique orderIDs from table 1 of user 11 and all the details of that 10 ids from table 2. If I do LIMIT 25 then I don't get all the information. 
I want my output as:

```
orderID userId orderName orderTime... table2ID orderID item    price 
 1        11                            101       1    Apple   1.99
 1        11                            102       1    Banana 2.99
 1        11                            103       1    Grapes  0.99
 3        11                            105       3    chicken 1.99
 3        11                            106       3     apple   1.99
```

Comment: Think of your logic.  Your query join the 2 tables then select 10.  What you want is select 10 from table 1, then get all records for the 10 records from table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM a
       WHERE a.userID = 11
       LIMIT 10) as a
JOIN b
  ON a.orderID = b.orderID
```

Comment: Thank you @Juan Carlos.. This way I am getting what I wanted ..I want to get the recent 10 records..
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM a
       WHERE a.userID = 11 order by a.orderTime DESC
       LIMIT 10) as a
JOIN b
  ON a.orderID = b.orderID
If I do this I get nothing..

Comment: That is weird. Try just `SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.userID = 11 order by a.orderTime DESC LIMIT 10` first

Comment: Yes, it worked. But it id taking so much time to load..So I am looking for that.. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Do you have index for userID? A composite id for tableA `(userid, orderTime)` may help